# Continually Encountering A Fatal error While Compiling Litecoin Source Code in MacPorts

Tags: macos, macports

I'm trying to write a demo cryptocurrency and have attempted to compile litecoin via Macports, but keep getting errors.  The first error I encountered was this:

> alert.cpp:6:10: fatal error: 'boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp' file not found

I'm not sure if I entered the command correctly, but this keeps happening. Does anyone have any suggestions or instructions on how to resolve this?  Thanks.

Comment: so, is the file in the path? can you show your command?

Comment: "I'm not sure if I entered the command correctly" - and neither do we. Perhaps you could supply it?

Comment: I'm having this same problem. How did you overcome it?

Comment: Did you ever get past this error? @ajbraus